# Maven cannot create SSH connection

Tags: java, maven, ssh, cygwin

I'm usin maven 2.2.1, and trying to do SSH connection to repository with settings:

`<server>`
                `<id>my-repository-ssh</id>`
                `<username>username</username>`
        `<passphrase>mypassphrase</passphrase>`
`<privateKey>c:/Users/f.lastname/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>`
   `</server>`

I'm working from Cygwin environment.

When I build project by `mvn clean install` maven can't connect to repository:

`[INFO] artifact com.someworld:common.configuration: checking for updates from my-repository-ssh`
`Password for username@10.0.1.25:`
`[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact com.someworld:common.configuration' could not be retrieved from repository: my-repository-ssh due to an error: Authentication failed: Cannot connect. Reason: Auth fail`
`[INFO] Repository 'my-repository-ssh' will be blacklisted`

But when I try to create connection by sftp command it works nice:

`$ sftp username@10.0.1.25`
`Enter passphrase for key '/home/F.Lastname/.ssh/id_rsa':`
`Connected to 10.0.1.25.`
`sftp>`

So what may be the reason of this problem?

Comment: Try to set the <privateKey> with a unix path instead of windows

Comment: maybe this helps: http://www.abdinoor.com/2009/06/03/cygwin-and-maven-deploy/

Comment: Why are you using ssh to connect to a repository and http ?